# How to observe 'boldTextStatusDidChangeNotification' using default notification center in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, notificationcenter

I'm trying to have observe running constantly in the app background which will trigger custom action if Accessibility Bold Text feature has been enabled via Mobile Device Settings.

My understanding is I need to add observe to the default notification center and the name of the notification is 'boldTextStatusDidChangeNotification'.

Can someone advice on the code sample for this?

Comment: see this for help : https://github.com/3sidedcube/ThunderBasics/blob/master/ThunderBasics/AccessibilityRefreshingViewController.swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the state of many accessibility options thanks to a bunch of events provided by the system.

Add an observer as follows:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(methodToBeCalled(notification:)),
                                       name: UIAccessibility.boldTextStatusDidChangeNotification,
                                       object: nil)
```

... and create the method to be fired when the appropriate event occurs:

```
@objc private func methodToBeCalled(notification: Notification) {
    //Create your actions here.
}
```

If you want further information or check a complete list of these events with code snippets, I suggest to take a look at [this site](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/development/#accessibility-options).